# What's the cost for blocking call such as sleep and URL fetch in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm wondering how blocking functions such as sleep() or url fetch affects the calculation of "frontend hours". I assume these call should not add to the "fronted hours" cause it basically waiting for something to happen. In the mean time, the request might take several more seconds to return.

Will google charge me more if my request sleeps for a while?

Comment: Honestly what possible use case would you have for using sleep?  It might not cost instance hours for the specific instance, but if instances take longer to serve front facing requests you will inevitably have more instances started which will cost you for another 15min for a new instance.

Comment: Hi, @TimHoffman, as our service call some external API like google drive API, sometimes we reached the quota limitation from service provider and need to back-off for several seconds. That's why I need to add call to sleep() before retry in the same request. Hope this can help. Cheers!

Comment: ick, instances with a requesting sleeping (threadsafe: false) can not service another request. 

In theory sleep doesn't block other threads but I would run some tests to make sure that an instance with a sleeping thread can serve another request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you get charged for running instances - instance that are sleeping are still a running process, so you get charged for them.